# undefined method when accessing attributes of a model (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, sti

I have 4 models: `Patient`, `Admin`, `Doctor`, `User`. `Patient`, `Admin` and `Doctor` extends `User`.

```
// patient.rb
class Patient < User
end

// doctor.rb
class Doctor < User
end

// admin.rb
class Admin < User
end
```

However, I cannot get child-class-specific attributes. When I call, for example `patient.fathername`, it gives me the error

**NoMethodError: undefined method `fathername' for #Patient:0x007fa4c172a188**

while I have `fathername` column in my `Patient` model.

```
//schema.rb
create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "fathername"
end
```

Made some research about the problem, and realized that other people who use STI also encountered with this problem. However, I could not understand any of the solutions and source of the problem. What is wrong with STI and getting attributes?

Comment: What is STI? Did you create a migration to create a `parents` table, or did you just edit `schema.rb`?

Comment: @eirikir I've properly created all models, and gave a **type** column to specify its type. STI is Single Table Inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You should add fathername field to the model User, because this is the one that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

STI works with only one table (in this case Users) and adds a field named "type" that saves the name of the Model that is saving the record, it saves "Patient" for patients records, "Doctor" for doctors records, etc. all in the same table Users.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've properly created my models. My User model has a type column that specifies the type: Patient, Doctor and Admin. However, I can not access the columns of Patient model.

Comment: I'll expand my answer, you need to create fathername field in Users table, STI uses the same table for all the models.